# In wpf, how to know what button was clicked and pass its ID to a function?

Tags: wpf

I am creating buttons dynamically in wpf. Say for example `btn1` and `btn2`: While clicking buttons, I would like to know which button is clicked? In addition, I have to pass that button id to a function.

```
private void btnAddTimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int counter =1;
    Button dynamicButton = new Button();
    dynamicButton.Name = buttonName + counter;//properties of button
    dynamicButton.Content = "Toggle";
    dynamicButton.Width = 75;
    dynamicButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    dynamicButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    dynamicButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(80,20,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and a global counter of some sort to seperate the dynamically created buttons from eachother.

```
Button dynamicButton = new Button();
dynamicButton.Tag = ++_globalCounter;
```

Then just pass the Tag property of the button clicked to the function and cast it to whatever type the counter is and you got your button ID.

Comment: could you please tell in detail

Answer (score 0):

Add a Click handler to `dynamicButton`. The `sender` argument then gives you the Button instance:

```
private void btnAddTimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    dynamicButton.Click += dynamicButton_Click;
}

private void dynamicButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dynamicButton = (Button)sender;
    ...
}
```

Comment: 'Button btnDynamic = (Button)sender;
            string name = btnDynamic.Name;'
@Clemens